# UIView Subclass: Detect the size of a UIView set up in Interface Builder which uses said UIView subclass as a custom class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder

I have a class called BannerAdView which is a subclass of UIView.

I have a UIView object which I set up in Interface Builder. I used Identity Inspector to set BannerAdView as its custom class.

How can BannerAdView detect the dimensions of the UIView that was set up in Identity Inspector?

self.frame.size.height and self.frame.size.width both return 0.000000

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in `BannerAdView`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the console output is: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Comment: Does it have a superview in interface builder?

Comment: Yeah. The superview is my main UIViewController. I think I could set up a class method in the main UIViewController to return the size of the UIView that I created in IB, and then call that class method from the UIViewSubclass, but I feel like there should be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: A controller cant be a superview. Is `BannerAdView` the root view in your view controller?

Comment: You could also try `didMoveToSuperview` instead of `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see dimensions of the UIView.

```
NSLog(@"My view's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myView.frame));
```

I hope it's will work

Comment: The class is a SubClass of UIView, so I assume you meant to write something like 
    "NSLog(@"My view's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));"
This returns: My view's frame is: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Comment: I did example.ı got in log => My view's frame is: {{40, 20}, {241, 455}} Can you look here have source code:  https://www.box.com/s/foqb5f3i910u80ycg1zw